# What "Index Status" actually show in old data?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

In February I got full control over 3 websites. All three existed for years before my arrival to the company. I noticed two of them (made by the same guy) had zero indexed page on Search Console's Index Status page before I updated my version of the site.

**The first two site looks something like this:**
[image]

You can clearly see when I started to work on the sites

**On the other hand the third site have data from times I wasn't there.**
[image]

What does it mean? **Someone else before me measured this so I get the data from times before me? Or the first two site wasn't in index at all?** (In other words: I get Search Console data OR real Google Index data in this tool when I start to measure a site?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two sites were apparently not being indexed by Google yet.

It's difficult to guess without knowing more, but likely causes would be a robots.txt blocking crawlers or noindex meta tags doing something similar. Alternatively, check all combinations of protocol/subdomain in Search Console to ensure they weren't indexed another way:

- `http://example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`